# How to match all <li> elements of an html code

Tags: regex

This is what I came up with, but its selecting only some li elements from the demo text

```
<li>(.+?)</li>
```

Demo text

```
<li><div class="tech-question">What is the most important feature of Java?</div><div class="tech-answer">Java is a platform independent language.</div></li>
<li><div class="tech-question">What do you mean by platform independence?</div><div class="tech-answer">Platform independence means that we can write and compile the java code in one
platform (eg Windows) and can execute the class in any other supported platform
eg (Linux,Solaris,etc).</div></li><li><div class="tech-question">What is a JVM?</div><div class="tech-answer">JVM is Java Virtual Machine which is a run time environment for the compiled
java class files.</div></li><li><div class="tech-question">Are JVM's platform independent?</div><div class="tech-answer">JVM's are not platform independent. JVM's are platform specific run time
implementation provided by the vendor.</div></li><li><div class="tech-question">What is the difference between a JDK and a JVM?</div><div class="tech-answer">JDK is Java Development Kit which is for development purpose and it includes execution environment also. But JVM is purely a run time environment and hence you will not be able to compile your source files using a JVM.</div></li><li><div class="tech-question">What is a pointer and does Java support pointers?</div><div class="tech-answer">Pointer is a reference handle to a memory location. Improper handling of
pointers leads to memory leaks and reliability issues hence Java doesn't
support the usage of pointers.</div></li>
```

Comment: This pattern does not support new lines.
so if<li> starts in line1 and end in line3 - this pattern won't find it.

Comment: [`<li>([\s\S]*?)<\/li>`](https://regex101.com/r/n3W2mU/1)

Comment: I suggest you replace the `demo text` by another short string, It's very hard for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tushar and  Michał M suggested I missed the newline .

Tushar's suggestion worked as expected

```
<li>([\s\S]*?)<\/li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "." won't match newline or line terminate characters. so will cut the string if it ends on a different line like Michal M said.

You could try

```
<li>(.*)</li>
```

Which would match any string which contains zero or more occurrences of "."